# Battery optimization constraint with max error

Tags: python, pyomo

I have formulated a battery dispatch optimization problem with the objective to minimize the imported power or equivalently to capture the excess of PV and maximize self-sufficiency.

```
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

#Set time period
model.timesteps = pyo.Set(initialize=pyo.RangeSet(len(pv)),ordered=True)

#Parameters
model.b_efficiency  = pyo.Param(initialize=etta)
model.b_cap = pyo.Param(initialize=battery_capacity)
model.b_min_soc = pyo.Param(initialize=battery_soc_min)
model.b_max_soc = pyo.Param(initialize=battery_soc_max)
model.b_charging_rate = pyo.Param(initialize=battery_charge_rate)

model.Ppv = pyo.Param(model.timesteps,initialize=pv.to_dict()['PV_Power'],within=pyo.Any)
model.Pdemand = pyo.Param(model.timesteps, initialize=demand.to_dict()['Panther_lodging_Cora'],within=pyo.Any)

#Variables
model.Pbat_ch = pyo.Var(model.timesteps, within = pyo.NonNegativeReals, bounds=(0, model.b_charging_rate))
model.Pbat_dis = pyo.Var(model.timesteps, within = pyo.NonNegativeReals, bounds=(0, model.b_charging_rate))
model.Ebat = pyo.Var(model.timesteps, within = pyo.NonNegativeReals, bounds=(model.b_min_soc * model.b_cap, model.b_max_soc * model.b_cap))
model.Pgrid = pyo.Var(model.timesteps)

# Define the constraints of the model
def BatEnergyRule(model, t):
    if t == model.timesteps.first():
        return model.Ebat[t] == model.b_cap/2
    else:  
        return model.Ebat[t] == model.Ebat[t-1] + (model.b_efficiency * model.Pbat_ch[t] - model.Pbat_dis[t]/model.b_efficiency)

model.cons1 = pyo.Constraint(model.timesteps, rule = BatEnergyRule)

def PowerBalanceRule(model, t):
    return model.Pgrid[t] == model.Ppv[t] - model.Pdemand[t] + model.Pbat_dis[t] - model.Pbat_ch[t] 

model.cons2 = pyo.Constraint(model.timesteps, rule = PowerBalanceRule)

def SimultaneousRule(model, t):
    return model.Pbat_dis[t] + model.Pbat_ch[t] <= np.max(model.Pbat_dis[t], model.Pbat_ch[t])

model.cons3 = pyo.Constraint(model.timesteps, rule = SimultaneousRule)
```

However, I am getting an error in the third constraint. With this constraint I need to ensure that battery charging and discharging cannot happen at the same timestep.

```
ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for Constraint cons3 with index
    1: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'args' referenced before assignment
ERROR: Constructing component 'cons3' from data=None failed:
    UnboundLocalError: local variable 'args' referenced before assignment
```

Any idea of what is causing the error and how can I bypass it?

Comment: `max()` is not a linear function and is not allowed in `pyomo` expressions.  You'll have to reformulate a bit, or possibly introduce another variable if you need to use `max`

Comment: As Airsquid said: You cannot use `max` python function in `pyomo`, rather you need to reformulate. Usually when modelling BESS operation there is a binary var `zBESS` to avoid the concurrent change/discharge processess and limit both to happen when dispatched. I guess that since you're using efficiency, maybe you donnot even need that constraint, but better check it out

Comment: @pybegginer Do you have any example of how to use the binary variable zBESS?

Comment: Suppose that `zBESSCh` and `zBESDis` are binary variables that decide whether if you're charging or discharging when one/zero. You can limit the charge/discharge rate with the `var`:  `Pbat_dis <= b_charging_rate*zBESSDis` and the same with charging. Then, avoid dis/charge with `zBESSDis +zBESSCh <=1`